# DISTINCT key but it returns duplicates; Query with multiple JOINS - Bug in my WHERE statement?

Tags: sql, salesforce-marketing-cloud

**Expectation**:
I would like to get all customers who bought an article from an specific category (i. e. drones) since the beginning of the year.

**Problem**:
I get duplicates; i. e. the customer purchased again at a different time (I don't care about that)

**Relationship of the tables**:

- [Master_CustomerData] *has_many*

  - [Master_OrderHeader] *has_many*

    - [Master_OrderedArticles] *belongs_to*

      - [Master_ArticleBase]

---

```
SELECT
    DISTINCT CD.SubscriberKey AS MCD_SubscriberKey
,   MAX(OH.OrderDate) AS OH_OrderDate
,   MAX(OA.OrderNo) AS OA_OrderNo
,   OA.ArticleNo AS OA_ArticleNo
,   OA.QuantityOrdered AS OA_QuantityOrdered
,   AB.Category AS AB_Category
,   CD.EmailAddress AS EmailAddress
,   CD.EmailLanguage AS EmailLanguage
,   CD.Gender AS Gender
,   CD.FirstName AS FirstName
,   CD.LastName AS LastName
FROM [Master_CustomerData] AS CD

INNER JOIN [Master_OrderHeader] AS OH
ON  CD.SubscriberKey = OH.SubscriberKey

INNER JOIN [Master_OrderedArticles] AS OA
ON OH.OrderNo = OA.OrderNo

INNER JOIN [Master_ArticleBase] AS AB
ON OA.ArticleNo = AB.ArticleNo

WHERE
        /* Category group  */
    AB.Category IN (811000)

AND OA.QuantityCancelled = 0

AND OH.OrderDate > '2018-01-01'

GROUP BY 
    CD.SubscriberKey
,   CD.EmailAddress
,   OA.ArticleNo
,   OA.QuantityOrdered
,   AB.Category    
,   CD.EmailLanguage
,   CD.Gender
,   CD.FirstName
,   CD.LastName
```

Comment: `distinct` applies to **all** columns in the select list.

Comment: You should check out using the [`group by`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp) clause by itself, as it looks like you want uniqueness by (CustomerID, CategoryID) pair.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name As a beginner could you explain your comment in more detail? Does it mean the combination of all columns is distinct? How can I set the key distinct without the other columns? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my working solution. I removed the "distinct", maxed "AB.Category" and grouped by what has to be distinct.

Thx, for all answers...

```
SELECT
    CD.SubscriberKey AS MCD_SubscriberKey
,   MAX(OH.OrderDate) AS OH_OrderDate
,   MAX(OA.OrderNo) AS OA_OrderNo
,   MAX(AB.Category) AS AB_Category
,   CD.EmailAddress AS EmailAddress
,   CD.EmailLanguage AS EmailLanguage
,   CD.Gender AS Gender
,   CD.FirstName AS FirstName
,   CD.LastName AS LastName
FROM [Master_CustomerData] AS CD

INNER JOIN [Master_OrderHeader] AS OH
ON  CD.SubscriberKey = OH.SubscriberKey

INNER JOIN [Master_OrderedArticles] AS OA
ON OH.OrderNo = OA.OrderNo

INNER JOIN [Master_ArticleBase] AS AB
ON OA.ArticleNo = AB.ArticleNo

WHERE
    /* Category defined: Dornes, cameras, outdoor, consoles */  
    AB.Category IN (
        211000,
        212000,
        ...
        791700
    )

    /* Article not Cancelled */
AND OA.QuantityCancelled = 0

    /* OrderDate */
AND OH.OrderDate > '2017-08-01'

GROUP BY 
    CD.SubscriberKey
,   CD.EmailAddress
,   CD.EmailLanguage
,   CD.Gender
,   CD.FirstName
,   CD.LastName
```

Answer (score 1):

for date  you have max date so should not select duplicated  value
if you use group by you don't need  DISTINCT

could be you need  sum for quantityOrdered too (if someone order two time the same product you have duplicated  rows)

```
SELECT CD.SubscriberKey AS MCD_SubscriberKey
,   MAX(OH.OrderDate) AS OH_OrderDate
,   MAX(OA.OrderNo) AS OA_OrderNo
,   OA.ArticleNo AS OA_ArticleNo
,   SUM(OA.QuantityOrdered) AS OA_QuantityOrdered
,   AB.Category AS AB_Category
,   CD.EmailAddress AS EmailAddress
,   CD.EmailLanguage AS EmailLanguage
,   CD.Gender AS Gender
,   CD.FirstName AS FirstName
,   CD.LastName AS LastName
FROM [Master_CustomerData] AS CD
INNER JOIN [Master_OrderHeader] AS OH  ON  CD.SubscriberKey = OH.SubscriberKey
INNER JOIN [Master_OrderedArticles] AS OA  ON OH.OrderNo = OA.OrderNo
INNER JOIN [Master_ArticleBase] AS AB  ON OA.ArticleNo = AB.ArticleNo

WHERE AB.Category = 811000 
AND OA.QuantityCancelled = 0
AND OH.OrderDate > '2018-01-01'

GROUP BY 
    CD.SubscriberKey
,   CD.EmailAddress
,   OA.ArticleNo
,   AB.Category    
,   CD.EmailLanguage
,   CD.Gender
,   CD.FirstName
,   CD.LastName
```